# How to request the reopening of a question unilaterally closed by a moderator?

Tags: support, closed-questions, reopen-closed

Sorry if this duplicates. I refer to [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/239862/50720) (which was automatically deleted).

On Apr 17 at 8:41, a moderator closed it unilaterally 'as unclear what you're asking'.

On Apr 17 at 14:30, I then edited my OP to try to clarify. I didn't see any comments explaining the apparent confusion or perceive any confusion; so I requested an explanation as a comment. I don't know if my comment reached the moderator in question; so I later tried to request a reopening and an explanation with a flag, which was declined as follows

> flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

, but didn't offer an explanation as I had hoped.

So can a moderator reopen a unilaterally closed question? What ought I to have done?

Comment: Corresponding [meta.english.se](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/6782/why-unclear-how-does-but-for-mean-if-it-were-not-for) question.

Comment: @MichaelT Thanks for the link. I asked it after reading the answers below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you edit a question while it is still "on hold" it will go into a reopen queue for review by everyone who can vote to reopen. There is no need to flag it to ask a moderator to reopen it.

If someone had commented on the question, you could @- reply them to let them know you've edited, but it's not necessary: usually different people end up reopening questions than those who closed them.

Answer (score 6):

When a diamond moderator closes your question, it's usually a slam dunk.

If your question was closed by the community users (high reputation users that aren't diamond moderators), hopefully they left comments.

Diamond moderators should also include any comments that may help you improve the question (if it can even be improved), so you know how to get it re-opened.

They don't have to, but according to the [Theory of Moderation](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/), they should.

The best way to get your question re-opened is to address the issues brought up by the close reason, and if that doesn't work (you edit it, it goes into the review queue, but doesn't get re-opened), then you should bring it up on your site's meta to determine what you're missing so it can be re-opened.